# Как заменить значение клавиши клавиатуры при помощи JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Как заменить значение клавиши клавиатуры при помощи JavaScript?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Простые контролы

Чтобы сделать простой виджет доступным через клавишу Tab, задайте `tabindex="0"` на HTML элементах `<div>` или `<span>`, из которых он состоит. Ниже представлен пример эмулирования чекбоксов. Вместо элементов input в примере используется .

Пример 1: Простой виджет, эмулирующий работу чекбосов путем смены изображений. Виджет использует tabindex, чтобы обеспечить доступ с клавиатуры.

Без атрибута tabindex, элементы `<span>` не смогут принимать фокус с клавиатуры

```
<div>
    <span role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0">
        <img src="checked.gif" role="presentation" alt="" />
        Добавить декоративную корзину с фруктами
    </span>
</div>
<div>
    <span role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0">
        <img src="checked.gif" role="presentation" alt="" />
        Добавить поющую телеграмму
    </span>
</div>
<div>
    <span role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0">
        <img src="unchecked.gif" role="presentation" alt="" />
        С предоплатой
    </span>
</div>
```

Сгруппированные контролы

Безусловно есть необходимость создания более сложных виджетов. В качестве примеров можно привести меню, панели табов, различные динамические таблицы, представления для информации, имеющей древовидную структуру. Для таких контролов родительский элемент должен иметь атрибут `tabindex="0"`. В таком случае он сможет попасть в фокус с клавиатуры. Все дочерние элменты (пункты меню, отдельные табы, ячейки, строки) должны иметь `tabindex="-1"`, чтобы не попадать в фокус при нажатии tab. Пользователи должны иметь возможность путешествовать по дочерним элементам при помощи стрелочек на клавиатуре. (Более полное описания того, как должен быть реализован доступ с клавиатуры для часто встречаемых виджетов, смотрите на DHTML Style Guide.)

Ниже приведен пример, который демонстрирует использование этой техники для реализации вложенного меню. После того, как в фокус попадает основной элемент меню `(<ul>)`, разработчик должен программно управлять фокусом, реагируя на нажития клавиш со стрелочками. Для описания техники управления фокусом внутри виджета смотрите раздел «Управление фокусом внутри виджета» ниже в данной статье.

Пример 2: Меню, использующее атрибут tabindex для осуществления доступа с клавиатуры

```
<ul id="mb1" tabindex="0">
  <li id="mb1_menu1" tabindex="-1"> Шрифт
    <ul id="fontMenu" title="Шрифт" tabindex="-1">
      <li id="sans-serif" tabindex="-1">Sans-serif</li>
      <li id="serif" tabindex="-1">Serif</li>
      <li id="monospace" tabindex="-1">Monospace</li>
      <li id="fantasy" tabindex="-1">Fantasy</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="mb1_menu2" tabindex="-1"> Стиль
    <ul id="styleMenu" title="Стиль" tabindex="-1">
      <li id="italic" tabindex="-1">Наклонный</li>
      <li id="bold" tabindex="-1">Жирный</li>
      <li id="underline" tabindex="-1">Подчеркнутый</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="mb1_menu3" tabindex="-1"> Выравнивание
    <ul id="justificationMenu" title="Выравнивание" tabindex="-1">
      <li id="left" tabindex="-1">Слева</li>
      <li id="center" tabindex="-1">По центру</li>
      <li id="right" tabindex="-1">Справа</li>
      <li id="justify" tabindex="-1">По ширине</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Атрибут tabindex был представлен в спецификации HTML 4. Он позволяет задать порядок, в котором элементы будут получать фокус при навигации с клавиатуры. Текущая реализация, описанная в HTML 5 draft specs.

Comment: вы, возможно, написали ответ не к тому вопросу)

Comment: это пример, зайдите в HTML 5 draft specs найдите нужную вам клавишу и напишите свой виджет(значение).